# Move an element of an array from start to end

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this multi dimensional array:

```
$array48= array(
 array("2017-06-30-104",1498858541000,39.3322,-122.9027,2.11,0,"U",36)
);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( 
                 [0] => 2017-06-30-104
                 [1] => 1498858541000 
                 [2] => 39.3322 
                 [3] => -122.9027 
                 [4] => 2.11 
                 [5] => 0 
                 [6] => U 
                 [7] => 36                       
                ) 
      )
```

i want to move `$array48[0][0]` to the end, and i do this:

```
function id_fine($array_disordinato){
    $number= count($array_disordinato);
    for($a= 0; $a < $number; $a++){
       $element=  $array_disordinato[$a][0];

       unset($array_disordinato[$a][0]);
       array_push($array_disordinato[$a],$element);
    } 
    return $array_disordinato;
}

id_fine($array48);
```

Works but I don't understand why the OUTPUT is:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( 
                 [1] => 1498858541000 
                 [2] => 39.3322 
                 [3] => -122.9027 
                 [4] => 2.11 
                 [5] => 0 
                 [6] => U 
                 [7] => 36 
                 [8] => 2017-06-30-104 
                ) 
      )
```

The position of each element is wrong. It should be:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array (                      
                 [0] => 1498858541000 
                 [1] => 39.3322 
                 [2] => -122.9027 
                 [3] => 2.11 
                 [4] => 0 
                 [5] => U 
                 [6] => 36  
                 [7] => 2017-06-30-104                     
                ) 
      )
```

Comment: The keys in a numerically index array are persistent just as in an associative array. If you delete one, then it is gone, until it is set again. If you want a _dynamically_ indexed array take a look at the `array_values()` function.

Comment: You `unset($array_disordinato[$a][0]);`, remember? [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) just removes the value, it doesn't reindex the array; it doesn't even know the value you asked it to unset was in an array and it wouldn't care anyway because it's not its job to care about arrays. [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) also doesn't reindex the array. It just finds the greatest numeric key, increments it and stores the value there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your `id_fine` function reset the array values of your array using [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

```
$array_disordinato[0] = array_values($array_disordinato[0]);
return $array_disordinato
```

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest you to use [`array_shift`](http://php.net/array_shift) for moving your first to last:

```
array_push($array48[0], array_shift($array48[0]));
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/832981)

or use:

```
$array48[0][]= array_shift($array48[0]);
```

<sup>Thanks *Andreas* for comment!</sup>

Single liner would do what you want to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1498858541000
            [1] => 39.3322
            [2] => -122.9027
            [3] => 2.11
            [4] => 0
            [5] => U
            [6] => 36
            [7] => 2017-06-30-104
        )

)
```

---

So, no need of complex function `id_fine` with `unset` and then `array_values`

---

From [DOCS](http://php.net/array_shift):

> *array_shift()* shifts the first value of the array off and returns it, shortening the array by one element and moving everything down. ***All numerical array keys will be modified to start counting from zero*** while literal keys won't be touched.

Comment: No need for array_push either `$array48[0][]= array_shift($array48[0]);` https://3v4l.org/CbcDT

Comment: Yeah either way :)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that result because you unset the position (`unset($array_disordinato[$a][0]);`) therefore that position no longer exists; What you want to do is create an entire new array with the new results.

By using what you have, the bloiw code will show you how to fix the issue:

```
$array48= array(
 array("2017-06-30-104",1498858541000,39.3322,-122.9027,2.11,0,"U",36)
);

function id_fine($array_disordinato) {
    $number = count ($array_disordinato);

    for($a= 0; $a < $number; $a++) {
       $element = $array_disordinato [$a][0];

       unset($array_disordinato[$a][0]);

       // HERE: after you unset the array you want to re-order back so it starts from 0
       // with this line only you should be fine :)
       $array_disordinato[$a] = array_values ($array_disordinato[$a]);

       array_push($array_disordinato[$a],$element);
    } 

    return $array_disordinato;
}

var_dump (id_fine($array48));
```

Answer (score 1):

[`unset($array_disordinato[$a][0]);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) just removes the value, it doesn't reindex the array. It doesn't even know the value you asked it to unset was in an array and it wouldn't care anyway because it's not its job to care about arrays.

[`array_push($array_disordinato[$a],$element)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) also doesn't reindex the array. It just finds the greatest numeric key, increments it and stores the value there.

There are several ways to reach your goal. One of them is to use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) after you re-order the values. `array_values()` ignores the existing array keys; it gets only the values and produces new indices starting from `0`.

Another option is to use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) instead of `unset()`. It extracts a slice from the array (you need from index `1` until the end) and, by default, it reindexes the array it returns. You can then use `array_push()` or just [`[]`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying) to append the value you already saved in `$element`:

```
function id_fine(array $array_disordinato)
{
    // Use the array keys to iterate over the array; it is safer
    foreach (array_keys($array_disortinato) as $a) {
       // Copy the first element to the end
       $array_disordinato[$a][] = $array_disordinato[$a][0];
       // Ignore the first element
       $array_disordinato[$a] = array_slice($array_disordinato[$a], 1);
    }

    return $array_disordinato;
}
```